How can I get a 3D form when rotate the polygon $ABCD$ around the line $AB$
I have polygon $ABCD$ here $A(1,0)$, $B\left (\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$, $C\left (-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$, $D(-1,0)$. How can I get a 3D form when rotate the polygon $ABCD$ around the line $AB$.
a = {1, 0};
b = {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
c = {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
d = {-1, 0};
Graphics[{Blue, Polygon[{a, b, c, d}], 
  Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {1, -0.1}],
  Text[Style["B", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {1/2, 
    Sqrt[3]/2 + .1}]
  }]




Similar with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/301459/72111
Calculate the volume.

Clear["Global`*"];
a = {1, 0};
b = {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
c = {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
d = {-1, 0};
reg = Polygon[{a, b, c, d}];
line = InfiniteLine[{a, b}];
RegionPlot[reg, 
 Epilog -> {Red, line, Point[{0, .4}], Blue, 
   Arrow[{{0, .4}, RegionNearest[line]@{0, .4}}]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Integrate[
 2  π*RegionDistance[line, {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ reg]


(7 π)/4.



Draw the solid.

Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
poly2d = reg;
{aa, bb, cc, dd} = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ {a, b, c, d};
poly3d = Polygon[{aa, bb, cc, dd}];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[poly3d];
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, {aa, bb}, 2  π];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.1}];
breg = BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh];
Show[bmesh[
  "Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> 
    Directive[FaceForm[Directive@{Opacity[.5], Cyan}], EdgeForm[]], 
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, poly3d, Blue, Arrow[{bb, aa + .5 (aa - bb)}]}]]



Another way to draw such surfaces. Write the parametric form of the segment line as {1-t,t}.{p1,p2}, 0<=t<=1,and rotate such lines around AB with θ.

Clear["Global`*"];
a = {1, 0};
b = {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
c = {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
d = {-1, 0};
{aa, bb, cc, dd} = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ {a, b, c, d};
ParametricPlot3D[
 RotationTransform[θ, aa - bb, 
    bb]@({1 - t, t} . # & /@ Partition[{aa, bb, cc, dd}, 2, 1, 1]) // 
  Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]



The way as below too slow.

Clear["Global`*"];
a = {1, 0};
b = {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
c = {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
d = {-1, 0};
{a, b, c, d} = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ {a, b, c, d};
preg = ParametricRegion[{RotationTransform[t, a - b, b]@{x, y, 
      z}, {RegionWithin[Polygon[{a, b, c, d}], Point@{x, y, z}], 
     0 <= t <= 2 π}}, {x, y, z, t}];
RegionPlot3D[preg, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2]
preg // Volume // FullSimplify


(7 π)/4.

